# Should this be closed as a dupe?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, specific-question

I ran across this question yesterday: [Heroku. Find Postgres database encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34405565/1394393). The user asks how to perform an action where the command line is not an option. However, [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16434925/1394393) to their question was found in a question that specifically asked for command line usage.

Would it be better to close as a duplicate since the other question contains a general answer that solves the problem? (Note that this answer is *not* the accepted one.) Or should we leave it open and post an answer because the other question includes specifications that are not an option for this situation?

From a practical perspective, I lean toward closing. Answering this question would just be duplication of information, and guiding users asking about the new situation toward the old question is a reasonable and useful outcome. But I'd like some feedback before voting to close.

Comment: Maybe the original question's title should be edited to omit "using the command line". The answers will still answer the question, but maybe if it was more generic a question more people would find themselves looking at the answers?

Comment: I considered that perspective. It could pretty easily be edited into some kind canonical question, I think.